# React input onChange lag (many textfields)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have quite a large form with many textfields inside, there are about 60-70 textfields inside.

Certainly it begins to lag and I know that the re-rendering could be a problem, also of the reason of having all values in the component state. I have no idea how to split it correctly or how I should solve that.

**Main Component -> View**

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
value1: '',
...
value60: '',
});

return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <form>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xl={12}>
                        <Breadcrumb breadcrumb={breadcrumb}/>
                    </Grid>

                    <BlockInputBasic handleChange={handleChange.bind()} values={values}/>
                    <BlockInputTarget handleChange={handleChange.bind()} values={values}/>

                </Grid>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

**Child Component**

```
export default function BlockInputBasic(props) {


    return (
       <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Name"
          name="name"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          required
          value={props.values.name}
          variant="outlined"
       />
       <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Name2"
          name="name2"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          required
          value={props.values.name}
          variant="outlined"
       />
       ....
       <TextField
          fullWidth
          label="Adress60"
          name="Adress60"
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          required
          value={props.values.name}
          variant="outlined"
       />

    );
}
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You should really reconsider your approach here. It's really 'painful' to see 60-70 textfield manually typed and using single `useState`.

Comment: Split up to more states? I just began with react, therefore it's all new for me...

Comment: You may consider to use useReducer rather than useState.

Comment: You mean e.g. redux in order to get all values after clicking on save?

Comment: your problem is just too many fields, and too many value inside one state, you should definitely split up. Maybe one component with its own state so each can render by itself. Get form value via form instead of state. Your scenario doesn't seem anything to do with `useReducer` nor `redux`. It's just too many to render at the same time.

Comment: @Yunhai I now did it like you told me - thank you for your input and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise state with same keys as name prop of textfields

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
 name1: '',
 ...
 name60: '',
});
```

Set state in event handler as

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
 setValues({
   ...values, 
   [e.target.name]: e.target.value
 })
}
```

```
<TextField
  fullWidth
  label="Name"
  name="name1"
  onChange={props.handleChange}
  required
  value={props.values.name1}
  variant="outlined"
/>
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Makes no difference. He will still experience problems with input lag as long as he justify 60+ input fields with a single state.

Comment: How is this gonna solve the problem? the asker want to optimize, not instructions to update the `TextField` state.